# Python Unit-test Mocking, unable to patch `time` module that's being imported in `__init__.py`

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I've the following code in the **__init__.py** file

```
from time import sleep
from functools import wraps

def multi_try(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        count = 0
        while count < 5:
            resp = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if resp.status_code in [200, 201]:
                return resp
            sleep(1)
            count += 1
    return inner
```

While writing tests for the above decorator I'm not able to patch the the *time.sleep* properly.

See the test below, even though I've patched time module, still the sleep function inside the decorator getting called, thereby test case require 5+ seconds to finish.

```
def test_multi_try_time():
    with patch("time.sleep") as tm: 
       mocker = MagicMock(name="mocker")
       mocker.__name__ = "blah"
       resp_mock = MagicMock()
       resp_mock.status_code=400
       _json = '{"test":"twist"}'
       resp_mock.json=_json
       mocker.return_value = resp_mock
       wrapped = multi_try(mocker)
       resp = wrapped("p", "q")
       assert mocker.call_count == 5
       mocker.assert_called_with('p', 'q')
       assert resp == None
```

Also I tried this,

`with patch("dir.__init__.time" ) as tm:`

and

`with patch("dir.utils.time" ) as tm:`

That resulted in

`AttributeError: <module 'dir/__init__.pyc'> does not have the attribute 'time'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was

```
with patch("dir.sleep" ) as tm:
```

Instead of,

```
with patch("time.sleep") as tm:
```

Comment: Looks like you got along just fine :+1: